# Using SQL to edit text on website

Tags: sql

I'm working on a basic admin panel for a site of mine but have run into a problem. I haven't done much SQL so sorry if this is fairly basic knowledge.
The Site has a JS Slider which shows our sites best selling products currently (As seen here : http://www.theyard-store.co.uk/)
I created a form so I could easily update the slider, but I don't know the best way of linking it to the database.
I thought about just having a separate table for each product and a separate form then just use SQL UPDATE to do this.
Is this the best way of doing it? Is there more efficient methods?

Comment: are you talking about separate database tables or separate web page tables?

Comment: Separate database tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I thought about just having a separate table for each product "

No, seperate tables for each product is a nightmare...imagine a new product being added and you having to go through each line of code to refer to the new product table added.

My recommendation is to have a single product table...something simple like "Product_ID, Product_name, coupl other data points, etc.." as you product table.  A second table (product_form?) can be created that refers to the product_ID in your product table and then store relevant data on your form information.

My preference is to never over-write data in your database either.  If you include a 'status' or 'active_flag' column in this new product_form table, you can simply insert a new line and set the old line to inactive.  This way you save all previous entries for the product_form record and can build a history/workflow/validation process.

Comment: +1, "soft" deletes (aka delete by changing status value) are necessary when you FK your products to your orders.  When you no longer sell something, you still need to have a record of those orders.